# Writing a Python Dictionary consisting of lists for values to CSV in long data format

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key-value, long-format-data

I have a Python Dictionary that consists of keys an value pairs where each values is composed of a list. The lists vary in length.  The dictionary has the following format:

```
diseaseDict = {'NCT01266330': ['Oxidative Stress', 'Inflammation'], 
    'NCT01266343': ['Glaucoma', 'Acute Primary Angle-closure Glaucoma'], 
    'NCT01266356': ['Traumatic Brain Injury'], 
    'NCT01266369': ['Mastocytosis'], 
    'NCT01266382': ['Osteoarthritis', 'Spinal Diseases', 'Ligament Rupture', 'Lower Extremity Fracture', 'Neurological Disorders'], 
    'NCT01266395': ['COPD']}
```

I need to write it to a CSV file in the long format.  I've tried a couple of iterations but couldn't get it just right.  **How do I write Python Dictionaries like this to a CSV using the long data format ?**

This is what the Python dictionary with its keys and values (from lists) would look in the long data format:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

header = ['key', 'valuesList']

with open('file.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerow(header)

    for key, value in diseaseDict.items():
        for i in value:
            writer.writerow([key, i])
```